# How to get the text from the Other field in a google forms question to be used in the visualization?

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

On a check all that apply (checkbox type) question, some respondents used the options I created and othere people used the other box. The issue is that for the people who used the other box, the data is not being aggregated into the existing options. See YouTube or Google Drive, to see the issue.

I don't want to have all the 1,1,1... answers, want the data to be aggregated.

[image]

Comment: Welcome. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: _I don't want to have all the 1,1,1... answers, want the data to be aggregated._ Suggestion: why not provide an example of what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I learned that tha google visualization on a form is not directly tied to the google sheets responses tab. My original thinking was that if you change a value in that responses sheet that the visualization would change, but that isn't true.